# AEM CQ5.6 Add config page in other page

Tags: aem

I have homepage(template) and homepage(page) also
I create config(template) and config(page)

I want to when the homepage will create the config page is inserted into the homepage through identifier(id) `config`.

(Later config page will be used to config other components, but to start its body must only show the message from 'Config page'. inherit from `foundation/components/page`.)

How to implement this functionality?

Comment: Please elaborate more  on what you are trying to do

Comment: When I create a page in the WCM through a "homepage template" will be created "page homepage". I want to at the moment of creating a homepage it contains the content of the configpage, which should be found through the ID. Is it possible to do such a thing?

Comment: Well you can do that by using `<cq:include path="configPage"
    resourceType="myapp/components/configPage" />` But I don't understand why an ID is needed. When you can directly add page. using cq:include

Comment: Add the above tag inside your homepage.jsp It will include the config.jsp inside it

Comment: Please select answer is this is solved your problem. As this may also help others know the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do that by using `<cq:include path="configPage" resourceType="myapp/components/configPage" />`

But I don't understand why an ID is needed. When you can directly add page. using **cq:include**

Add the above tag inside your homepage.jsp It will include the config.jsp inside it